# Welchen Fall benutze ich in einem ob-Satz?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-case

Ist "Artikel" hier Dativ oder Akkusativ?

> "Könntest Du bitte nachschauen, ob die Artikeln brauchbar sein könnten?"

Comment: Ich hab den Titel der Frage mal so unformuliert, dass er etwas allgemeingültiger ist. Falls dir das nicht in den Kram passt, einfach einen Rollback durchführen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Weder noch, "Artikel" ist in diesem Nebensatz das Subjekt und steht im Nominativ.

Für sich genommen würde der Satz wie folgt lauten:

> Die Artikel könnten brauchbar sein.

"Die Artikel" sind das Subjekt und daher im Nominativ. Daran ändert sich auch dann nichts, wenn der Satz zum Nebensatz wird und sich die Wortstellung entsprechend ändert.

> Könntest du bitte nachschauen, ob die Artikel brauchbar sein könnten.

Answer (score 1):

Meiner Meinung nach kommt hier der Nominativ zum Zuge. Also:

> Könntest Du bitte nachschauen, ob die Artikel brauchbar sein könnten?

Dass der Dativ falsch ist, ist eigentlich sofort ersichtlich, da das Interrogativpronomen zu *brauchbar* *wer* ist und nicht *wen*.

Der Akkusativ scheint hier zunächst logisch, da die *Artikel* passiv sind, nicht aktiv. Jedoch steht *Artikel* in einem anderen Teilsatz als *Du*, womit sie zum Subjekt werden, die gemäss Definiton immer im Nominativ stehen müssen.

Comment: Wir sollten vielleicht noch darauf hinweisen, dass der Gebrauch des Konjunktivs im gegebenen Beispiel ungewöhnlich ist.

Comment: Der Weg über das Interrogativpronomen hilft Lernenden überhaupt nicht und viele fühlen sich davon auf den Arm genommen (ich bin Lehrer und habe da einige Erfahrung mit)

Comment: @Emanuel Ich denke selbst den meistens Muttersprachler gibt diese Antwort ein Rätsel auf. Wer weiß denn schon, was ein Interrogativpronomen ist.